# What is the default capture of a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was reading an article which stated the following

> The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either
>   capture default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always
>   captured by reference, even if the capture default is =.

I am having difficulty understanding the above statement - What is either of the capture default? Does this mean that if I use `=` as the capture (which means copy variables in the current scope) it implicitly adds `this` to the capture as well thus allowing me to use `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is either of the capture default?

`=` or `&`.

Comma-separated capture list (the thing enclosed in `[]`) can optionally begin with one of capture-defaults: `=` or `&` (which may be the only element in the list). If a capture-default is present and you attempt to use a variable in your lambda that has to be captured (an automatic variable or `this`), the capture-default will capture that variable by value (`=`) or by reference (`&`).

> Does this mean that if I use `=` as the capture it implicitly adds `this` to the capture

Yes, but only if you actually use it (directly or by accessing class members). This behavior is deprecated, see below.

A capture default doesn't capture any variables unless you actually use them in the lambda.

---

C++20 deprecates the capture of `this` by `=`. Capturing `this` essentially means capturing "current object by reference", so it's weird that `=` captures everything else by value, but the current object by reference.

Supposedly it was originally made that way because capturing `*this` (the current object by value) was only added in C++17.

Comment: why is it called a default ? is it implicitly added to the lambda if we dont specify anything ?

Comment: @MistyD See the edit. You can also read the explanation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), under 'Explanation - captures'.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up . could u tell me what u mean by automatic variable ?

Comment: @MistyD One declared at a function scope (instead of class or namespace scope).

Comment: I suppose there had to be a way to distinguish a capture between const versus non-const reference, but `this` versus `*this` only perpetuates the confusion between pointers and references.